# HTTP 405 Error thrown by application on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, html, tomcat

I have 2 similar web forms that post data to my java application.
Two separate functions handle this POST request, but they are exactly the same.
But, one form POSTs successfully while the other doesn't and throws a HTTP 405 Error.

Including HTML form code:

```
 <form action="BiApi/a/b" method="post" id="formquery" name= "makeQuery">
    <!----Text Boxes---->
    <input type="submit" value="Query" onclick="if(this.value=='Query'){ this.value='Wait processing query...'; this.style.color='#000';}"/>
 </form>
```

Java functions that handles the request

```
@POST
@Path("/b")
@Produces({"text/csv"})
public String b(
        @FormParam("reportType") int reportType,
        @FormParam("preStart") String preStart,
        @FormParam("preEnd") String preEnd
        ){
    try {

        CampaignQueryDto campaignQueryDto = new CampaignQueryDto();
        campaignQueryDto.setReportType(reportType);
        campaignQueryDto.setPreEnd(preEnd);
        campaignQueryDto.setPreStart(preStart);

        if (campaignQueryDto.isAuthorized()) {
            return csvForDto(campaignDao.xyz(campaignQueryDto));
        } else {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }
}


/*..Method 2 ..*/

@POST
@Path("/bUK")
@Produces({"text/csv"})
public String bUK(
        @FormParam("reportType") int reportType,
        @FormParam("preStart") String preStart,
        @FormParam("preEnd") String preEnd){
    try {

        CampaignQueryDto campaignQueryDto = new CampaignQueryDto();
        campaignQueryDto.setReportType(reportType);
        campaignQueryDto.setPreEnd(preEnd);
        campaignQueryDto.setPreStart(preStart);
        if (campaignQueryDto.isAuthorized()) {
               return csvForDto(campaignDao.xyzUK(campaignQueryDto));
        } else {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }
}
```

My web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>abc</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.argusinformation.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BiApi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The only difference in the code for the 2 forms is the name of the Java function. i.e. if one is b then the other is bUK.

One returns the result while the other gives a 405 error after submitting the form.

Any potential solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your both method annotation used separately.

Comment: Hi @SachinSarawgi: I have provided both the methods with their annotations in my question.

Comment: "*The only difference in the code for the 2 forms is the name of the Java function. i.e. if one is b then the other is bUK.*" .. I doubt this .. Can you put exact HTML form code which you are using ..

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, as SachinSarawgi mentioned - could you provide us at least both methods you have used (according to overall copyright policy and/or confidentiality of the application's source code etc., which disallow you to provide its completed version)?

EDIT. It seems like you forget to add `campaignQueryDto.setReportType(reportType);` line into your first method's code. Fixing it should help.

Comment: I have provided both the methods with their annotations in my edited question

Comment: Now we're talking :)

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't fix it. Still getting the same error for bUK while the other works fine.

Comment: Did you try to uncomment the `htmlForDto`section in bUK?

Comment: Sorry, i hadn't pasted the functions currently. But now I have corrected that. They are exactly the same.